# How to show datas under the value in angular2/ionic2

Tags: arrays, json, angular, select, ionic-framework

home.ts

```
items = [];

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
     this.initializeItems();}
     initializeItems() {
     this.items = [
       {
        'title': 'Fiat',
        "models" : [
          {"model":"500L","value":1,"specs":"hatchback"},
          {"model":"Linea","value":2,"specs":"sedan"}
        ]
      }]
```

brand.html

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Models</ion-label>
      <ion-select id="secim" [(ngModel)]="values">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let m of item.models" value="{{m.value}}">{{m.model}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <div class="" *ngIf="values==1">
    <h1 *ngFor="let m of item.models">{{m.model}}:{{m.specs}}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="" *ngIf="values==2" >
    <h1 *ngFor="let m of item.models">{{m.model}}:{{m.specs}}</h1>
  </div>
```

It's appear like this

500L:hatchback
Linea:sedan

but I want to do like this

(if select value=1)
500L:hatchback

(if select value=2)
Linea:sedan

How could I do? Thank you

Comment: what do you get when by adding this to the template in between the select and the divs: `{{values}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of what you are doing now, why not store the selected model to a variable, of which you can then show `model` and `specs`, so for example have a variable `selectedModel`:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Models</ion-label>
  <ion-select id="secim" [(ngModel)]="selectedModel">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let m of item.models" [value]="m">{{m.model}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

And then just have one `div` to show the other properties:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedModel">{{selectedModel.model}}:{{selectedModel.specs}}</div>
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/1xwhtwB5YjKHDbRzusHP?p=preview

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it fit your requirements :)